# No sound from monitor speakers, headphones working fine

Tags: sound, 18.04

This seems all too common of a problem, yet none of the other fixes I've found have worked for me.

The speakers do work, they work fine in windows 10 and they are detected in ubuntu but no sound comes from them.

My monitor is connected to my GPU through DVI-D, there's a separate audio cable connecting the monitor to my motherboard.

This is on my custom built desktop.

If you need anymore information feel free to ask.

Note: No the speakers aren't muted. In settings they show up as `Digital Output (S/PDIF) - Built-in Audio` and the only profile available for them is `Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output`

Comment: Was this an upgrade to 18.04?

Comment: @PaulBenson No, fresh install from almost a year ago.

Comment: Have the same issue. Were you able to solve it?

Comment: @LongSmith No, still living with it.